# how to populate select option in laravel? from hard coded options

Tags: laravel

I just wanna populate select option for EDITING the data saved in database? Can someone help me please? I have just started learning laravel.

The code given here is from create.blade.php file, Need to modify this to be edited

```html
<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6 xl4 offset-xl2 ">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">person_outline</i>
    <select name="civil_status">
        <option value="" disabled {{ old('civil_status')? '' : 'selected' }}>Select a Civil Status</option>
        <option value="Married" @if (old('civil_status') == "Married") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Married</option>
        <option value="Single" @if (old('civil_status') == "Single") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Single</option>
        <option value="Divorced" @if (old('civil_status') == "Divorced") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Divorced</option>
        <option value="Widowed" @if (old('civil_status') == "Widowed") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Widowed</option>
        <option value="Seperated" @if (old('civil_status') == "Seperated") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Seperated</option>
    </select>
    <label>Civil Status</label>
</div>
```

```
   public function edit($id)
    {
        $departments  = Department::orderBy('dept_name','asc')->get();
        $cities       = City::orderBy('city_name','asc')->get();
        $states       = State::orderBy('state_name','asc')->get();
        $genders      = Gender::orderBy('gender_name','asc')->get();

        $employee = Employee::find($id);
        return view('employee.edit')->with([
            'departments'  => $departments,
            'cities'       => $cities,
            'states'       => $states,
            'genders'      => $genders,
            'employee'     => $employee,
            'toBeEdited'   => $employee

        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your `edit.blade.php` view:

```html
<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6 xl4 offset-xl2 ">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">person_outline</i>
    <select name="civil_status">
        <option value="" disabled {{ old('civil_status')? '' : 'selected' }}>Select a Civil Status</option>
        <option value="Married" {{ old('civil_status') == "married" || $toBeEdited->civil_status == "married" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Married</option>
        <option value="Single" {{ old('civil_status') == "Single" || $toBeEdited->civil_status == "Single" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Single</option>
        <option value="Divorced" {{ old('civil_status') == "Divorced" || $toBeEdited->civil_status == "Divorced" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Divorced</option>
        <option value="Widowed" {{ old('civil_status') == "Windowed" || $toBeEdited->civil_status == "married" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Widowed</option>
        <option value="Seperated" {{ old('civil_status') == "Separeted" || $toBeEdited->civil_status == "Separated" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Seperated</option>
    </select>
    <label>Civil Status</label>
</div>
```

You just need to pass the model to be edited to your view trough your controller, like this:

```php
function edit($id)
{
    return view('edit', [
        'toBeEdited' => YourModel::find($id),
    ]);
}
```

Or you can  use dependency injection in your edit function:

```php
function edit(YourModel $model)
{
    return view('edit', [
        'toBeEdited' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Now you have access to the `model` in your view as `$toBeEdited` variable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How are you doing that? can you edit your question with code?

Comment: Could you please chack the question again, i have updated with what you said... Will it work this way? as I'm passing other four models data with edit form

Comment: yeah, But, It doesn't populate with data saved in the database!!

Comment: you said it was hardcoded... Which data should be populated?

Comment: It's OK now. Working.  There was a minor error in edit.blade. Corrected. cool. Thanks a lot buddy!!

Comment: Glad that i can help you :)